# Oracle cumulative sum DB performance vs lots of code

Tags: oracle, cumulative-sum

I have table x with 53 columns and 1 million or so rows. The first column is an identifier, and the following 52 columns are monetary transactions that occur each week from a particular date.

eg.

```
id,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5..w52
a1,0,5,1,4,0..43
a2,7,0,6,9,4..27
```

I need a cumulative sum of all those weeks transactions per id. One solution in I found was to use unpivot to get 52 rows per id, then apply an aggregate sum.

```
sum(transaction) over (partition by id order by week asc)
```

My issue here is that I now have a table with 60 million rows and Oracle is performing very slowly (prohibitively so) sorting through getting the sum.

Another option is that I took each column and manually added them together as follows.

```
select 
 id,
 w1,
 w1+w2,
 w1+w2+w3,
 w1+w2+w3+w4,
 w1+w2+w3+w4+w5,
 ..
 w1+w2+w3+w4+w5..w49+w50+w51+w52

from x
```

The issue here is that it's a lot of code (writing it out has been a pain!) to get what should be a simple formula.

Is there anyway I can tune my table (index / partition) to speed up an aggregate sum over so many rows, or any code I can use with my original table to achieve these results with the least effort?!

Comment: "The issue here is that it's a lot of code (writing it out has been a pain!)". Why is it a pain? write it once, make a view out of it and then you don't have to look at it again. You can even write an SQL statement easily to generate that SQL for you as a one off.

Comment: The real issue is that you have a poorly designed data model.  You would have found it a lot easier properly nomrmalised table.

Comment: @APC maybe so. What would you suggest is the way to structure the data behind this? My source data is ID and transaction and date. The transactions occur sporadically but I'm tracking performance week by week and need to see weeks where nothing happened etc.

Answer (score 1):

create a view to hide the "lot of code". eg:

```
SQL> desc tester;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 W1                                                 NUMBER
 W2                                                 NUMBER
...
 W49                                                NUMBER
 W50                                                NUMBER
 W51                                                NUMBER
 W52                                                NUMBER
```

then run an SQL like (in 11g you can use `listagg` instead of `wm_concat` to the same effect):

```
select 'create or replace view v_tester as select id ' from dual
union all
select * 
  from (select ','||replace(wm_concat(column_name) over (order by column_id), ',', '+') || ' as col' || rownum
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'TESTER'
   and column_id >= 2
 order by column_id)
union all
select ' from tester;' from dual;
```

to generate the DDL like:

```
create or replace view v_tester as select id 
,W1 as col1
,W1+W2 as col2
,W1+W2+W3 as col3
,W1+W2+W3+W4 as col4
,W1+W2+W3+W4+W5 as col5
```

etc..then run that. now your code is hidden by the view and was relatieley easy to produce.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Unless I'm missing something, I still have to take the output of that code and paste then run to create the view?

Comment: @user2207949 yes (or use execute immediate on it to create it for you) but this is a one off thing.